# Invertibility of product of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ be  a  $m \times n$ matrix and $B$  be a $n \times m$ matrix over real number with $m < n$.
>
> Which one is correct ?
>
> 1. $AB$ is  always singular
> 2. $BA$ is always singular

My answer :

Option $1$  is  true  because take  $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&&0&&0\\0&&1&&0\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$B=\begin{pmatrix} 1&&0\\0&&1\\0&&0\end{pmatrix}$$ Then $AB = I$

Option 2 is not  True

Is  my answer  correct ?

Comment: Similar question  -https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2838189/singularity-of-the-product-of-two-rectangular-matrices

Comment: From your question it seems that you don't use the definition of a singular matrix in a correct way...is the unity matrix invertible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$BA$ is always singular!

Hint:

$A$ is $m \times n$ and $m<n$ implies $Ax=0$ has a non-zero solution

$\textbf{Added}$:

> Result:  $A$ is $m \times n$ and  $m<n$ implies $Ax=0$ has non zero solution $x_0$.

Proof:

> View the matrix $A$ as a linear map $A:\Bbb{F}^n \rightarrow \Bbb{F}^m, x \mapsto Ax.$
>
> By dimension theorem, $$dim\;\Bbb{F}^n=rank\;A+null\;A $$
> $$n\leq m+null\;A$$
> So, $null\;A \geq n-m >0$,. Hence $Ax=0$ has a non zero solution (say $x_0$). QED

Now $$(BA)x_0=B(Ax_0)=B.0=0$$
Hence $BAx=0$ has non zero solution, concluding $BA$ is singular.

Comment: im not getting can u elaborate more,,,,,@Chinnapparaj

Comment: Let $x_0$ be the non zero solution of $Ax=0$. The same $x_0$ will be the solution to $(BA)x=0$. Can you see why?

Comment: ok   i was thinking that  $ (AB)x$= $AxB = 0.B =0  $  is  its  correct ??.....what im thinking about ur answer  that  Ax= 0  has  non zero solution that mean  (BA)x = (B).0=0

Comment: I edit my answer and now i think you are ok!

Comment: For your first part, we do not conclude anything about $AB$. It may be singular or non singular. For your example, it is non singular. On the other hand consider $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1& -1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix} -1\\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$. Then $AB=0$

Comment: okss  ,,,thanks  u @chinnapparaj

Comment: You are welcome!